# Laravel 5 not able to sign in with Auth user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Hello fellow developers, 
I'm fairly new to Laravel but this login issue is getting on my nerves.

Yesterday it worked fine but today I arrived at work and I can't login, it throws the "These credentials do not match our records." error but I know the data is correct. I haven't changed anything in my user class in days and I don't understand why it isn't working today..

Please keep in mind I'm a noob with Laravel so try not to be very harsh :)

Thanks in advance!

**Login.blade.php**

```
 @extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i>Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**AuthenticationController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**HomeController.php**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\PAT;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
      $pats = PAT::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(6)->get();
        return view('home', compact('pats'));
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

  public $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
   {
       $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
   }

   public function pat(){

    return $this->hasMany(PAT::class, 'user_id');
   }

   public function patf(){

    return $this->hasMany(PATF::class, 'user_id');
   }
}
```

**routes.php**

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

//test routes

Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('pages.about');
});
```

**UsersTable**

```
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are encrypting your password twice.

If you want to use the model accessor (I mean `setPasswordAttribute()`) to encrypt the password whenever it is saved/updated, then you may remove the encryption in the `AuthenticationController`.

Your `create()` method would be just like follows

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name'     => $data['name'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => $data['password'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: it worked @phaberest, thanks! What is blowing my mind is that my create() method was like that since the beginning of my project and only today it stopped working and i have no idea why!

Comment: You probably re-seeded or created a new user, it worked before since you probably had already created the user before changing the `setPasswordattribute()` in the model ;)